# Stone Weirstrass proof clarification

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

I was reading through a proof of the Stone - Weierstrass approximation theorem:

Let $X$ be a compact metric space. Let $A\subseteq C^\mathbb{R}_b(X)$ an algebra which contains the constant functions and separates points of $X$. Then $A$ is dense with respect to the metric induced by $\lVert . \rVert_u$ in $C^\mathbb{R}_b$

Notation:

$\lVert . \rVert_u: \text{sup norm}$.

$C^\mathbb{R}_b(X): \text{Bounded and continous real valued functions defined on X}$

---

In one part of the proof one wants to show that if $f\in A$, then $|f|\in \overline A$ (the uniform closure of $A$ in $C^\mathbb{R}_b(X)$).

The proof is as follows:

From previous steps one has a sequence $(p_n)_n$ of real polynomials, pointwise increasing in $[0,1]$, that converges uniformly to the function $\sqrt x$ for $x\in[0,1]$. If we consider the sequence
$$
\left(p_n\left(\frac{f^2}{\lVert f \rVert_u}\right)\right)
$$
this converges uniformly to $\sqrt\frac{f^2}{\lVert f \rVert_u} = \frac{|f|}{\lVert f \rVert_u}$, hence $|f|\in \overline A$.

---

What I understand is that using Dini's theorem for uniform convergence one can say that convergence is uniform.

What I don't understand is what makes $|f|\in \overline A$? How I understand it is that the approximation is being done by the polynomials. But my understading of uniform closure is that of wikipedia: 'The uniform closure of a set of functions A is the space of all functions that can be approximated by a sequence of uniformly-converging functions on A.

However I'm not sure if $p_n\in A$ for every $n$. (I'm aware that it is possible that they could be contained in $A$, but what if $A$ is some algebra that excludes them?).

I'll appreciate if someone gives me a hand on my confussion.

Comment: It does not even make sense to ask whether $p_n\in A$: $p_n$ is a polynomial on $\mathbb{R}$ and $A$ consists of functions on some different space $X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $p$ is any polynomial with real coefficients and $g\in A$, then $p(g)\in A$.  This is just because $A$ is an algebra, so it is closed under multiplication and addition.  We have $p(g)=\sum_{i=0}^n c_i g^i$ for some constants $c_i\in\mathbb{R}$.  This expression is just a big sum of products of elements of $A$, so it is in $A$ as well.

So in particular, since $f^2/\|f\|_u\in A$, $p_n(f^2/\|f\|_u)\in A$ for each $n$.  Thus their uniform limit $\sqrt{f^2/\|f\|_u}$ is in $\overline{A}$.